# symspell 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, nlp

[image: dataset]
i want to correct spell i try this code is work

```
from symspellpy import SymSpell, Verbosity

input_term = "diperbakin tertnduk kenaps"
suggestions = sym_spell.lookup_compound(input_term, max_edit_distance=2)

for suggestion in suggestions:
    print(suggestion.term)
```

output : diperbaki tertunduk kenapa

but i want to apply this code in my dataset but i got this error

```
comment = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    suggestions = sym_spell.lookup_compound(row["Comment"], max_edit_distance=2)
    comment.append(suggestions[0].term)
    
df["Comment"] = comment
df.head()
```

and this the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3b0edc49798e> in <module>()
      1 comment = []
      2 for index, row in df.iterrows():
----> 3     suggestions = sym_spell.lookup_compound(row["Comment"], max_edit_distance=2)
      4     review.append(suggestions[0].term)
      5 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/symspellpy/helpers.py in parse_words(phrase, preserve_case, split_by_space)
    196     if preserve_case:
    197         return re.findall(r"([^\W_]+['’]*[^\W_]*)", phrase)
--> 198     return re.findall(r"([^\W_]+['’]*[^\W_]*)", phrase.lower())
    199 
    200 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: In your first code snippet, ```sym_spell``` isn't defined.  In your second code snippet, what is ```row["Comment"]```?  Try printing out the value before that ```suggestions = ...``` line.

Comment: sorry for my post i already defined sym_spell, 
from symspellpy import SymSpell

sym_spell = SymSpell()
corpus_path = "wiki-id-formatted.txt"
sym_spell.create_dictionary(corpus_path)